# Passing previous Powershell command properties into a piped command

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Can someone show how to pass a property from one Powershell command into the next piped command (in order to pull properties from both levels of the request)?

I need to get archive mailbox sizes for users in Exchange Online.  An example of this is here:

`Get-EXOMailbox | get-MailboxStatistics -archive | select displayname,totalitemsize`

When you run this, obviously you are grabbing properties from the second command.  I need to also grab the identity property tied to `Get-EXOMAilbox`, the first command (which shows the user's active mailbox and is useful for subsequent actions.

Thanks!

Comment: Look at -Pipelinevariable

Comment: Looks like the `-Identity` parameter for `Get-MailboxStatistics` only takes one identity at a time, so you need to loop over the results of the Get-AXOMailbox cmdlet

Comment: Let me know if `Get-EXOMailbox | select -ExpandProperty Identity | Get-MailboxStatistics -Archive` works

Answer (score 1):

As [Doug Maurer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67254991/passing-previous-powershell-command-properties-into-a-piped-command/67257264#comment118877376_67254991), you might want to take advantage of the [`-PipelineVariable` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7.1#pipelinevariable):

```
Get-EXOMailbox -PipelineVariable mailbox |Get-MailboxStatistics -Archive |Select @{Name='DisplayName';Expression={ $mailbox.DisplayName }},TotalItemSize
```